# Usage of "is so"

Tags: sentence-patterns

Can we use: "The machine is so designed that the output retains the color of the input." or it is better to write "The machine is designed in a way such that ...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but I recommend using neither; the first sounds odd and the second prolix.  I advise saying 'the machine is designed *so that* the output retains the colour of the input', as this is more common.